# Haskell, using function with list comprehensions

Tags: haskell

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
slice :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
slice from to xs = take (to - from + 1) (drop from xs)

trimBoard :: Board -> Int -> Board
trimBoard s y = slice ((y*3)) (((y+1)*3)-1) s

getBox :: Board -> Int -> Int -> [Sequence]
getBox s y x = [ (trimBoard c x) | c <- (trimBoard s y)]
```

Specifically, I'm trying to run a function, take the result `[[int]]`, then map another function onto that result. Which haskell appearantly abhors, and I need to use some combination of "lambda functions" and other wizardry I cant read or comprehend at all to get this chugging along.

Is there any simple way to do this that wont require a 7 month course in mathematical function syntax?

As mentioned above, the result, board, is [[int]], and sequence is simply [int].

The errors it produces are

```
sudoku.hs:139:19: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Int]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: Sequence
        Actual type: Board
    • In the expression: (trimBoard c x)
      In the expression: [(trimBoard c x) | c <- (trimBoard s y)]
      In an equation for ‘getBox’:
          getBox s y x = [(trimBoard c x) | c <- (trimBoard s y)]

sudoku.hs:139:29: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Int]’
      Expected type: Board
        Actual type: Sequence
    • In the first argument of ‘trimBoard’, namely ‘c’
      In the expression: (trimBoard c x)
      In the expression: [(trimBoard c x) | c <- (trimBoard s y)] Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Unless `Board` is a synonym for `Sequence`, your types don't agree.

Comment: ``getBox s y x = [ (trimBoard c x) | c <- (trimBoard s y)]`` is rejected by ghc with a flood of errors which I dont understand. I THINK they are complaining that x is supposed to be an int, but has instead somehow become an [int], but I am unsure about that.

Comment: Board is [[int]], and sequence is [int]. The top two functions operate fine, on their own. Only the third fails.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the errors.  Also add the definitions of the `Board` and `Sequence` types.  This is for future readers and searchability.

Comment: `c` in expression `c <- (trimBoard s y)` has type `[Int]`, but the first argument of `trimBoard` need type `Board`, i.e. `[[Int]]`, it is not match. In addition, `getBox` finally has type `[Board]` not [Sequence]`.

Comment: Odd. Why? trimBoard :: Board -> Int -> Board, produces a board. why doesnt c <- trimBoard produce a board? @assembly.jc

Comment: @RNPF, list comprehension `[ ... | c <- trimBoard... ]` means *for each element* `c` of the list `trimBoard`.  So `c` has the *element type* of whatever list you are binding it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have written all your functional code correctly but have not correctly specified your type signatures.  `trimBoard` expects a `Board` as its first argument, but you have passed it `c` which is a single row.

What you may be complaining about is that `trimBoard` ought to work perfectly well if you pass it a single row instead of a complete board.  And indeed it does, you just need to learn how to say so:

```
trimBoard :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
```

That it, `trimBoard` takes a list of *any* type, and an `Int`, and returns a list of that same type.  Now you are not restricted to passing lists of lists of `Int`, and everything works fine.

You could also have omitted the type signature of `trimBoard` and Haskell would have inferred this one, which is the most general one.  (But it is good to write type signatures and learn how to do so -- in fact, with practice, this becomes an invaluable tool that I miss dearly in other languages).